# Going back to the first Contour in Emgu after iterating through them

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

So basically i'm using Emgu.CV to detect contours, and after I get the contours of an image:

```
Contour<System.Drawing.Point> contours;
using (var stor = new MemStorage())
{
     contours = gray_image.FindContours(
        Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
        Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,
        stor);
}
```

I basically iterate through them using:

```
for (i = 0; 
    (context.Contours != null) && (i < this.config.MaxNumberContours); 
    context.Contours = context.Contours.HNext)
```

Can I iterate through them again afterwards? The documentation [says that it is similar to h_next pointer in OpenCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/9bee392d-b500-773f-aa59-41e3ffe4d663.htm), what does this means?

Answer (score 0):

First, where did you find that code to iterate through the contours? The normal way, taken from Emgu [webpage](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp), is something like this:

```
for (Contour<Point> contours = cannyEdges.FindContours(); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
{
 ...
}
```

The contours are not indexed, but each *Contour* contains a pointer *HNext* that points to the next contour. If *HNext* is null, there are no more contours.

If you want to go through them again, you can use the *HPrev* pointer, which points to the previous contour. If *HPrev* is null, you have reached the first contour.

Another option, if you are running through the contours many times, is to save the contours in a *List* like this:

```
var contourList = new List<Contour<Point>>()
for (Contour<Point> contours = cannyEdges.FindContours(); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
{
 contourList.Add(contour);
}
```

Now you can use the *contourList* to iterate through the contours and you can access them by an index.